# Error: jump to label 'failed' [-fpermissive], GCC vs VS

Tags: c++, gcc, png

We added some new code in our PNG decoding routines for our game engine. The additional chunk defined is just there to read some values -- no big deal.

On Visual C++, it compiles just fine. On GCC, which is what we primarily use, we now get a strange issue that has never happened before:

[compile_problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOkkZ.gif)

This is the added code:

```
    /* read grAb chunk */
png_unknown_chunk *unknowns;
int num_unknowns = png_get_unknown_chunks(png_ptr, info_ptr, &unknowns);

for (int i = 0; i < num_unknowns; i++)
{
    if (!memcmp(unknowns[i].name, "grAb", 4))
    {
        png_grAb_t *grAb = reinterpret_cast<png_grAb_t *>(unknowns[i].data);
        grAb->x = EPI_BE_S32(grAb->x) + 160 - width / 2;
        grAb->y = EPI_BE_S32(grAb->y) + 200 - 32 - height;
        img->grAb = grAb;
        break;
    }
}
```

Looks just fine to me. This is the only thing added to our original file. The complete file is here:
[goto Line 59 of image_data.cc](https://github.com/3dfxdev/hyper3DGE/blob/master/epi/image_png.cc)

And the function where this bombs out:
image_data_c *PNG_Load(file_c *f, int read_flags)

I don't understand what could be happening, as this worked perfectly fine before and never had issue with cross-initialization or our case handling.

If I could get some help, I would really appreciate it!

---

Comment: Please post  [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: I figured as much, but the strange thing is that VS doesn't bomb out with this, while GCC does...:S

Comment: Well, something in [0,2] compilers is right. Impossible to tell without a MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors seem pretty clear: there are jumps to label `failed:` from before the initialization of `int num_unknowns` to after it, so that int will have garbage values.  This is forbidden in C++ ( but not in C).

One solution is to put

```
int num_unknowns = 0;
```

at the beginning of the function, and change the third line of the code sample you posted to just an assignment to `num_unknowns`.

Another solution is to instruct GCC to allow this, with the `-fpermissive` option, as the error itself indicates.

Comment: While your solutions do silence the warning, you fail to prove that the resulting code is correct and yields the desired behavior on all relevant platforms..

Comment: @Baum: Obviously they are already jumping past lots of assignments, but had all their initialisations at the top of the function to allow the jumps. Then they added a new variable but forgot to declare it at the top of the function. So, do that. It's obviously just as correct as what they had before the change, and given its name I don't think the `failed` block is going to assume that all the assignments in the function were successful, so this isn't even really a misuse of `goto`.